# Javascript Odata Create Record Datetime issue

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm-2013

I am creating records using Odata JavaScript. While creating record i am setting datetime field. The Javascript creates record properly. Issue is in CRM it sets the date to one day before.

Suppose i am setting date to 2nd April 2014, it will set in CRM 1st April 2014.

What can be the issue? Is this time zone issue?

Thanks!

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I am using XrmServiceToolkit.Rest.Create() method to create record."http://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com/".

Answer (score 0):

It looks most likely a time zone issue. I would recommend you to use OData v4. In this version, the DateTime type is replaced with DateTimeOffset type.

Comment: There are some samples for reference if you are using WebAPI:https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ . Hope this may help you.